# Confine each exercise/question to one page using xsim

Tags: page-breaking, xsim

I can do the following:

```
\begin{samepage}
\begin{exercise}
Long text question or maybe a table and some stuff etc.
\end{exercise}
\end{samepage}
```

But I would prefer to have this automated (since I feel like this would be possible).

I have tried declaring a new exercise environment. Trying to follow the `\tcolorbox` example in the `xsim` package manual but this does not work.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{xsim}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    
    \DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{customex}
      {%
        \begin{samepage}
        \subsection*
          {%
            {
            \XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}%
            \IfInsideSolutionTF
              {
                %\GetExerciseParameter{exercise-name}%
                ~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}.%
              }
              {%
                ~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}
                \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}
                  { {\normalfont\itshape\PropertyValue}}%
              }%
            }
          }
      }
      {\end{samepage}}
      
    \xsimsetup{exercise/template = customex}
    
    \begin{document}
        \begin{exercise}
            \lipsum[1-4]
        \end{exercise}
        
        \begin{exercise}
            \lipsum[1]  
        \end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

The result is Exercise 1 being broken across 2 pages, instead of the desired Exercise 1 on page 1 and Exercise 2 on page 2.

Comment: I have also tried using exercise/pre-hook{/begin{samepage} }  and exercise/post-hook which also breaks exercise 1 over 2 pages.

Comment: Maybe you could use \newenvironment{question}{\begin{samepage}\begin{exercise}}{\end{exercise}\end{samepage}} ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way without having to define any template would be

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{exercise}{%
  \begin{samepage}%
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{exercise}{%
  \end{samepage}%
}
```

Since `\samepage` “only” does some penalty settings this won't ensure that your exercises always are on the same page. (E.g., this doesn't help for your example).

If you want to be *really* sure that exercises stay on one page and if you also are sure that exercises never are longer than one page you can use a `minipage`:

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{exercise}{%
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{exercise}{%
  \end{minipage}\par
}
```

Probably even better with some vertical space added:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim,lipsum}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{exercise}{%
  \vspace{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}
  \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{exercise}{%
  \end{minipage}\par
}


\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
  \lipsum[1-4]
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed work. But, the mere inclusion of hyperref, no matter the load order, breaks the result with all minipages on one page and just drifting off the bottom.

Comment: @JSchon edited with a version that works also with `hyperref` (but requires a rather recent LaTeX)

Answer (score 0):

I get good results with

```
\xsimsetup{
    exercise/begin-hook  = \begin{samepage},
    exercise/end-hook = \end{samepage},
    solution/begin-hook  = \begin{samepage},
    solution/end-hook = \end{samepage},
}
```

The solution from @cgnieder with pre-hook/post-hook gave strange effects.

Comment: What kind of strange effects? And in combination with which templates? Ideally you could post a MWE on xsim's issue tracker?